# Neo4j is drawing two relationships using APOC shortest path query based on relationship value, however it should be one

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

Im still new to Neo4j, Im trying to figure out how to get Neo4j to return and draw only the shortest path between two nodes. im currently using APOC procedure.

basically i have two nodes (Site-1 & Site-2) with two relationships between them (relationship-1 (Link, distance:10) & (relationship-1 (Link, distance:40).

[image: result screen shot is in the attachment]

I used the below APOC procedure

````
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(site1, site2, 'Link', 'distance') YIELD path, weight
Return path, weight ```

the graph returned with a drawing of two relationship between the two nodes, however it should only draw one. any idea on how i can return one only?
````

Comment: Pls give us sample data so qe ca simulate it. Thanks

Comment: It works on my system, can you share the statements, using which you created your graph?

Comment: Hello guys, i have attached the screenshot for the graph output, as you can see the graph is returning two links, however it should only return one link, if you look at the right hand you will see that in the Overview the returned values are 2 nodes and 1 link.

Comment: It's not an error. Neo4j browser will show you all the relationships of a node. Goto, to the table section, there you will see only one path is returned.

Comment: So, there is no way to make Neo4j to just draw the targeted relationship, in case i used a javascript to get the graph from neo4j, will i also get both links or only one?

Comment: Added an answer

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j browser is a tool, that makes cypher querying easier and also helps in visualizing the graph as well. What you are seeing is not an error exactly. Neo4j browser is configured by default, to show all the relationships of a node when expanded. It doesn't necessarily represent your query output. I replicated your case on my system, I also received the same graph.

[image]

But the actual query response is under the `Table` tab.

[image]

This is the whole response that I got:

```
[
  {
    "path": {
      "start": {
        "identity": 5,
        "labels": [
          "Site1"
        ],
        "properties": {}
      },
      "end": {
        "identity": 6,
        "labels": [
          "Site2"
        ],
        "properties": {}
      },
      "segments": [
        {
          "start": {
            "identity": 5,
            "labels": [
              "Site1"
            ],
            "properties": {}
          },
          "relationship": {
            "identity": 0,
            "start": 5,
            "end": 6,
            "type": "LINK",
            "properties": {
              "distance": 10
            }
          },
          "end": {
            "identity": 6,
            "labels": [
              "Site2"
            ],
            "properties": {}
          }
        }
      ],
      "length": 1.0
    },
    "weight": 10.0
  }
]
```

As you can see, only one path and weight are returned. This is what your query outputs and this is what your language driver will receive be it Javascript, java, anything.